# setting up Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode on a Mac

Tags: macos, hadoop, installation

I'm currently trying to set up Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode on my Mac, which is running Mountain Lion. I downloaded Hadoop 1.0.4 and I have taken the following steps, as detailed in "Hadoop in Action", by Chuck Lam:

1) Generate an SSH key pair: I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate a pair and did not set a password. I put the key in /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. I then copied this file to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. This allows me to SSH to my own machine from my own machine without providing a password.

2) Set up JAVA_HOME: I modified the conf/hadoop-env.sh to include `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home`, which I believe is my Java installation directory. (For reference, this directory contains bin, bundle, lib, and man.)

3) Set up the site conf files: I copy-pasted the configurations that were suggested in the book. They are:
core-site.xml

```
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 <description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose
 scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation. 
</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
 <value>localhost:9001</value>
 <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
 at.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

 <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
 <description>The actual number of replications can be specified when the
 file is created.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

4) Set up the masters and the slaves. My conf/masters and conf/slaves files simply contain localhost.

5) Format HDFS: `bin/hadoop namenode -format` I get the following output:

```
12/11/16 13:20:12 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu/18.111.53.8
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
Re-format filesystem in /tmp/hadoop-me/dfs/name ? (Y or N) Y
12/11/16 13:20:17 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
12/11/16 13:20:17 INFO util.GSet: 2% max memory = 39.83375 MB
12/11/16 13:20:17 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
12/11/16 13:20:17 INFO util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
12/11/16 13:20:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=me
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO common.Storage: Image file of size 119 saved in 0 seconds.
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-me/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
12/11/16 13:20:18 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu/18.111.53.8
************************************************************/
```

6) Launch: `bin/start-all.sh` I get the following output:

```
starting namenode, logging to /Users/me/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../logs/hadoop-me-namenode-dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /Users/me/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../logs/hadoop-me-datanode-dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /Users/me/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../logs/hadoop-me-secondarynamenode-dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /Users/me/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../logs/hadoop-me-jobtracker-dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /Users/me/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../logs/hadoop-me-tasktracker-dhcp-18-111-53-8.dyn.mit.edu.out
```

The text now claims that I should be able to run jps and get output similar to:

```
26893 Jps
26832 TaskTracker
26620 SecondaryNameNode
26333 NameNode
26484 DataNode
26703 JobTracker
```

However, I only get:

```
71311 Jps
```

So I assume that something is wrong, but have no idea where I went wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop logs will tell u why.

Check logs under `/Users/me/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../logs/`

I think the problem may be the permissions of `.ssh` directory is not correct.

Try `chmod 700 ~/.ssh; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`